# How GKE costs based on k8s container resources

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

There are two fields in k8s, requests, and limits. I want to know that whether GKE cost us on requests or limits.

If request is 1Gi and limits is 2Gi
Will I be costed for 1Gi or 2Gi?

Answer (score 4):

There are two different modes of operation in Google Kubernetes Engine: Autopilot (easier to manage, but less flexible) and Standard. They're billed [differently](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing#google-kubernetes-engine-pricing).

In Standard mode, you're essentially **billed for Compute Engine instances** used in your cluster. That means your requests and limits are only used indirectly, as you're expected to be responsible for setting up your cluster so that it's scaled according to those. When doing this, you should remember that some of each node's resources [are required to run the GKE and Kubernetes node components](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#node_allocatable) necessary to make that node function as part of your cluster.

In Autopilot mode, you're **billed for resources** - CPU, memory, ephemeral storage - requested by your currently scheduled Pods. The catch is that each Pod in Autopilot mode is [considered to be a Guaranteed QoS Class Pod](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#allowable_resource_ranges):

> Autopilot automatically sets resource limits equal to requests if you
> do not have resource limits specified. If you do specify resource
> limits, your limits will be overridden and set to be equal to the
> requests.

To be more specific, in your example 2 Gi limit will be overridden and set to 1 Gi, the same as request. You'll be billed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> If request is 1Gi and limits is 2Gi Will I be costed for 1Gi or 2Gi?

Yes, If you are on **GKE autopilot** and plus there will be additional fees (**$0.10/hour** for each cluster).

**If GKE standard mode**

If you are on GKE and using the cluster you will get a charge based on the `(If request is 1Gi and limits is 2Gi Will I be costed for 1Gi or 2Gi? won't affect anything)`

- Node size and count in GKE cluster
- GKE dashboard operational management cost ($0.10 per cluster per hour)
- Network in-out if applicable.

**If** **Autopilot**

- Autopilot clusters accrue a flat fee of **$0.10/hour**
- Resources CPU/Memory are charged in 1-second increments (Pricing you can check in doc for requested and limit)

If you check the GKE pricing document it's pretty easy and straight forward explaining everything : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing#google-kubernetes-engine-pricing

You can use the GCP **Pricing calculator** to count estimate the cost : https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator

**Update**:

If you have opened the Calculator, you might have noticed two different GKE modes. You can use that to estimate the cost.

[image]

Comment: Ok. Suppose I have 3 nodes in a cluster, each having 4CPUs. How many pods I can run with 1Gi request and 2Gi limit config? If it's 6 pods, then the limit is blocking the node but if it is 12 pods, then indirectly I am being costed by requests, right?

and according to your answer does it mean, that I will be charged for 3 nodes, irrespective of my pods running?

Comment: Not sure how you calculated CPU request/limit with `Gi` param, i think CPU uses the `m` param. `Gi` for memory maybe although if you are on normal mode, not using auto pilot you will be charged for `Node size (4 CPU or whatever RAM)` and `count` regardless of the Request/Limit you are setting for POD, deployment anything.

Comment: If you are on autopilot mode you will be billed for request/usage. maybe you have not visited calculator link shared in answer, it's pretty easy and straight to estimate, you will get two option at starting only Auto pilot and standard try using that.

Comment: Got it. I am using standard mode. Can you tell me how much CPU will be blocked from a node when a container is deployed, is it request or limit?